# How to display a pseudo field in a view

Tags: views, 8

I have created a pseudo field with this code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_extra_field_info().
 */
function MYMODULE_entity_extra_field_info() {

  $extra['node']['my_bundle']['display']['my_pseudo_field'] = [
    'label'       => t('Pseudo Label'),
    'description' => t('Pseudo description'),
    'weight'      => 100,
    'visible'     => TRUE,
  ];

  return $extra;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view().
 */
function MYMODULE_node_view(array &$build, EntityInterface $entity, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode, $langcode = 'fr') {

  if ($display->getComponent('my_pseudo_field')) {

    $build['my_pseudo_field'] = [
      '#markup' => 'This is my pseudo content',
    ];
  }
}
```

Everything is working fine, except that I couldn't add it in a view.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible. You need a views field plugin like it exists for real (non-pseudo) entity fields and then add it in `hook_views_data()` to  the node definition.

Comment: Thanks you 4k4. I assume I can create a computed field then add it in hook_views_data()

Comment: I meant a plugin, an example would be the path field of a node. The markup is placed in render() of the plugin class, see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21Plugin%21views%21field%21Path.php/function/Path%3A%3Arender/8.4.x

Comment: I have followed your idea and I could end up with a solution... you can see it below. One thing is still missing : the sort in the view doesn't works.

Comment: I think the best trade-off in this situation is to configure your view to display full nodes and choose a (newly added) dedicated view mode for display. Instead of letting your view display single fields. Displaying full nodes view modes will also display pseudo fields.

Answer (score 7):

With the help of 4k4, I could solve my problem... I will start by explain my first try, which could be a good solution in some cases, then I will explain/show how I finally end up.

Firstly I created my computed field in `hook_entity_base_field_info_alter` [Note that this is not a pseudo field this time]

```
function my_module_entity_base_field_info_alter(&$fields, EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
    if ($entity_type->id() === "node") {
      ...field is created here... will show you how to after
    }
}
```

Secondly, we need to create a class (that will perform the calculation) for the computed field (will show you after)

Thirdly, we can display this field in a view simply by implementing `hook_views_data_alter`... This is the beauty of this solution: the view integration is made very quickly. Here is the how the hook is implemented

```
function my_module_views_data_alter(array &$data) {
  $data['node']['my_computed_field'] = [
    'title' => t('My computed field'),
    'field' => [
      'id' => 'field',
      'default_formatter' => 'string',
      'field_name' => 'my_computed_field',
    ],
  ];
}
```

What was not good in my case, is the fact that my computed field does appears in all bundles (even if I use `setTargetBundle('my_bundle')` like showed below).

Thus I changed a little bit my computed field process creation:

**1-Create the computed field** in `hook_entity_bundle_field_info_alter` ... not in `_entity_base_field_info_alter` (As you can see, it is a float field... youn could use a string)

```
function my_module_entity_bundle_field_info_alter(&$fields, EntityTypeInterface $entity_type, $bundle)
{
    if ($entity_type->id() == 'node' && $bundle == 'my_bundle' ) {
        $fields['my_computed_field'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('float')
        ->setName('my_computed_field')
        ->setLabel(t('Nombre de litres total'))
        ->setComputed(TRUE)
        ->setTargetEntityTypeId('node')
        ->setTargetBundle('my_bundle')
        ->setClass('\Drupal\my_module\MyComputedFieldItemList')
        ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
            'type' => 'float',
            'weight' => 0,
        ])
        ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
    }

}
```

Note: if someone know the purpose of `->setTargetBundle('my_bundle')` I would be glad to read anything on it as I added it without knowing if it is mandatory/usefull.

**2-Extend `FieldItemList`** (MyComputedFieldItemList) [use the same name as in `->setClass('\Drupal\my_module\MyComputedFieldItemList')`]

The main point here is the protected function `computeValue` that will use $node to compute the value.

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\my_module;

use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemList;
use Drupal\Core\TypedData\ComputedItemListTrait;

/**
 * Item list for a computed field that displays the total liter for a soup.
 *
 */
class MyComputedFieldItemList extends FieldItemList
{

    /**
     *
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    use ComputedItemListTrait;

    protected function computeValue()
    {
        $node = $this->getEntity();
        if (! $node->isNew()) {
            $this->list[0] = $this->createItem(0, my_module_function_to_compute($node));
        }
    }
}
```

At this stage, you have a computed field that you can display in "my_bundle"... Lets go to the view integration

3-Alter `hook_views_data_alter` to tell views that you have a new computed field linked to a node. The main point here is the id `my_computed_field`

```
function my_module_views_data_alter(&$data)
{
    $data['node']['my_computed_field'] = array(
        'title' => t('My computed result'),
        'group' => t('Content'),
        'field' => array(
            'title' => t('My computed result'),
            'help' => t('bla bla.'),
            'id' => 'my_computed_field',
        ),
    );
}
```

4-Thanks to 4k4, I understood that you need to **create a plugin class** that will have a `render` function to show the result in the view. The second important thing here is the `@ViewsField("my_computed_field")` annotation that needs to be the same as the id in step 3

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Definition of Drupal\my_module\Plugin\views\field\ComputeField
 */

namespace Drupal\my_module\Plugin\views\field;

use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\field\FieldPluginBase;
use Drupal\views\ResultRow;

/**
 * Field handler to flag the node type.
 *
 * @ingroup views_field_handlers
 *
 * @ViewsField("my_computed_field")
 */
class ComputeField extends FieldPluginBase {

    /**
     * @{inheritdoc}
     */
    public function query() {
        // Leave empty to avoid a query on this field.
    }

    /**
     * @{inheritdoc}
     */
    public function render(ResultRow $values) {
        $node = $values->_entity;
        if ($node->bundle() == 'my_bundle') {
            return my_module_function_to_compute($node);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, everything runs fine:

- The field could be displayed (or not) in any display mode and you can change the settings in the UI as any regular field
- The field could be inserted in a node view
- There is a function `my_module_function_to_compute($node)` that you can put in your module. This function will compute the result of your field with the entity as argument (node here)

**One thing is missing**: the sort (in the view) doesn't work... I have to dig into it

Comment: After some digging, it seems that we can't sort a computed field... I would be happy to get another opinion.

Comment: Yeah seems so, no sorting. Seems you can actually only solve the sorting problem similar to how the [Computed Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field) does it, to create another field and on entity save store the computed data in it. And on entity view maybe recalculate the display with a field formatter if necessary. Sigh 